# Daylight saving Issue in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, save, dst

I have a very strange problem with DST. If I put my team in the Brasilia time zone and turn on "Time Setting summer time automatically" and if I try to create a new date in the browser on the day that daylight saving time begins with the time "00:00:00 "date that automatically creates me subtracts an hour. For instance:

**Daylight saving time starts on October 18.**

```
new Date ("2015-10-18T00:00:00") 
// the date is created: 2015-10-17 23:00:00 - this is wrong

new Date ("2015-10-18T01:00:00")
// the date is created: 2015-10-18 01:00:00 - this is fine
```

Any clues?

Comment: You can resolve this ambiguity by supplying the correct timezone into the dateString, like `'2015-10-18T00:00:00+02:00'` or similar. BTW, the output you see is incorrect only if the timezones on those dates are the same.